# read multiple values from OPC UA with opcua-asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, opc-ua

I'm looking for a way to read the values from multiple nodes at once instead of using a loop.

I created a list with the node objects from a CSV file.

```
for index, row in force_list.iterrows():
            tag = client.get_node(row['Address'])
            forces.append(tag)
```

This list I use in a loop to retrieve the values together with the timestamp and the node name.

```
 for i in self.forces:
       self.force_values.append((ts, str(i).split(".", 3)[-1], await i.read_value()))
```

This works but is slow because of the multiple requests to the server. Is there a way to read multiple values with one request with opcua-asyncio in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use read_values from client to read all values in one network request.

Example:

```
vals = await client.read_values(self.forces)
```

Comment: I already tried read.values but the performance is the same as with a loop.

Comment: read_values does one network call. So there is no network overhead. So its possible, that the server needs a long time to gather the requested nodes or your code is doing expensive operations. How many variables you are reading in one read_values?

Comment: I read 28 variables in one read_values